# Whats the best way to persist state in a node module?

Tags: node.js, module

I'm writing an `auth` module that contains several functions so my server can authenticate with an oAuth2 system using `client_credentials`. In the module I want to cache / save the credentials since they don't expire for some time (I'll refresh as needed).

Whats the best way to store the credentials?

Should I just create a `var` at the top of my node module? Should I create a `class` and instantiate it (`const auth = new MyClass()`) where my makes subsequent API calls (with the Bearer token)?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a `var` variable means to store data in RAM, which is not a comprehensive approach.

I suggest you look at Redis, which was developed mostly for your purposes.

Redis is used as a database and for cache, since it’s super fast because the data is stored “in-memory” contrary to other databases in which the data is usually stored “on-disk.”

Moreover, there some thoughts about the fact that Node.js is less efficient at storing data than Redis. This [article](https://medium.com/@stockholmux/redis-and-node-js-slug-out-in-process-variables-and-remotely-stored-data-23c04ffc5bff) will clear more about my point.

So, in general, I guess using Redis will bring you more advantages in storing credentials.